# vl_compilenn ('enableGpu', true) on matlabr2016b, visualstudio2015 MatConvNet compile GPU

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2015, cuda, gpu, matconvnet

I have the follow configuration:

1. Windows 10 64bit
2. Matlab r2016b, NVidia GeForce 920MX, compute capability 5.0, toolkit version 7.5
3. Visual Studio 2015 for community
4. MatConvNet beta 23
5. Cuda 8.0 (ga1 02/2017)
6. cuDNN 6.0 (04/2017)

When I compile with `vl_compilenn (only cpu)` the compile is correct.
But when I compile with: 
`vl_compilenn ('enableGpu', true)` 
or more specific with:
`vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true, 'cudaMethod', 'nvcc', 'cudaRoot', 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0', 'enableCudnn', true, 'cudnnRoot', 'C:\..\..\..\..\..\MatConvNet\cuda')`

I have the follow issue:

> vl_compilenn: CUDA: MEX config file: 'C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\src\mex\win64\mex_CUDA_win64.xml'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0/VC/../VC/bin/../../VC/INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Non Þ possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'corecrt.h': No such file
>   or directory  data.cu Error using vl_compilenn>nvcc_compile (line 540)
>   Command "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc" -c
>   "C:.........\MatConvNet\matconvnet-1.0-beta23\matlab\src\bits\data.cu"
>   -DNDEBUG -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_CUDNN -I"C:..........\MatConvNet\cuda\include" -DENABLE_DOUBLE -D__SSSE3__ -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\include"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\"  -O3
>   -Xcompiler /MD --compiler-bindir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC..\VC\bin" -o
>   "C:..........\MatConvNet\matconvnet-1.0-beta23\matlab\mex.build\bits\data.obj"
>   failed.
>
> Error in vl_compilenn (line 485) nvcc_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile,
>   flags.nvcc) ;

Also, i have copied the cudnn64_6.dll into the specific directory matlab/mex

If you have an idea, i would be gratefull, since I have made several attempt with another version of matconvnet (example b24), but the issue is similar.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved used the follows libraries and software:

1. Matlab r2017a
2. Visual studio 2015
3. MatConvNet beta 24
4. Cuda 8.0.66

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no bin folder so Create 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC..\VC\bin' folder. It will stay empty but compiling will finished.